# Ubuntu resolution changed to 1024 x 768

Tags: 13.04, resolution

Today when I start up my laptop the resolution have dropped to 1024 x 768. My native resolution is 1280 x 800. I tried searching for solution but it doesn't work. Its quite hard to use it sometimes.

I'm using Acer Aspire 4930 with Mobile Intel® 4 Series Express Chipset Family

This is what I get when I do ddcprobe on terminal

```
root@acer-aspire-4930:/home/acer_aspire_4930# ddcprobe  
vbe: VESA 3.0 detected.  
oem: Intel(r)Cantiga Graphics Chip Accelerated VGA BIOS  
vendor: Intel Corporation  
product: Intel(r)Cantiga Graphics Controller Hardware Version 0.0  
memory: 65472kb  
mode: 1280x1024x256  
mode: 1280x1024x64k  
mode: 1280x1024x16m  
mode: 1024x768x256  
mode: 1024x768x64k  
mode: 1024x768x16m  
mode: 640x480x16m  
mode: 800x600x64k  
mode: 800x600x16m  
mode: 640x480x256  
mode: 800x600x256  
mode: 640x480x64k  
edid:   
edid: 1 3  
id: 4444  
eisa: AUO4444  
serial: 00000000  
manufacture: 1 2006  
input: analog signal.  
screensize: 30 19  
gamma: 2.200000  
dpms: RGB, no active off, no suspend, no standby  
dtiming: 1280x800@60  
monitorid: AUO  
monitorid: B141EW04 V4
```

My xorg.0.log

http://pastebin.com/QHcMnp79

Comment: I tried apt-get update, apt-get upgrade, updating my graphics driver

Answer (score 0):

You can change the resolution from **System Settings** > **Displays**:

[image: Resolution changing]

Comment: My native is 1280x800 but the maximum resolution that I can choose is 1024x768. It also recognizes my graphic card as Intel(r)Cantiga Graphics